# Lightweight and extensible C compiler front-end

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

is there anyone that knows if there is a lightweight C compiler front-end? I really just need lexing + parsing + semantic checks I need to do code generation and static analysis on that. Thanks in advance

Alberto

Comment: lcc and tcc are pretty lightweight and easy to hack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try TCC: http://bellard.org/tcc/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html), an open source front end to LLVM.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK then, I wouldn't call it "lightweight" either :)